# The branch 3.x of the Linux kernel vanilla won't work under Android - the 2.6 does

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, arm

I have successfully compiled a goldfish kernel 2.6.x for the Android emulator-arm, the problem is that the same `.config` file and the same compilation script won't work for the linux stable branch ( checkout via git ).

I have to take extra steps with a vanilla kernel? Someone got linux 3.x working on an emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel changes for ARM SoCs are pretty slow to make their way the kernel mainline (if at all) - not least as there are 5 or 6 ARM SoCs all trying to get changes in.

Your challenge will be to find the kernel tree which is used as the integration branch for a given SoC, and on which Android kernel releases are based.   There is no canonical source of information for this.

[Linaro](http://www.linaro.org/) is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a vanilla Linux kernel in Android. A number of Android specific changes were made. See: http://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Features.